# Find a lower bound for the probability that their average lies between 8 and 12.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Now suppose 20 real numbers are chosen independently from [0,20] with uniform probability. Find a lower bound for the probability that their average lies between 8 and 12.

for this I knew the mean would be 10, then I decided to take another integral of $$\int_{8}^{12}\frac x {20}\,dx,$$, but was not coming up with a reasonable number as well. Lastly, I tried to use chebychevs inequality, but still couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use Chebyshev's inequality to find an *upper* bound for the probability that their average lies *outside* $[8,12]$. Explicitly, if $X_1,\ldots,X_{20}$ are our random variables and $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ then

$$P\left(\frac{S_{20}}{20}\notin[8,12]\right)=P\left(\left|\frac{S_{20}}{20}-10\right|>2\right)\le\frac{\operatorname{Var}(\frac{S_{20}}{20})}{4}=\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X_1)}{80}$$

where we used that $\operatorname{Var}(\alpha X)=\alpha^2\operatorname{Var}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(S_n)=n\operatorname{Var}(X_1)$. Once you calculate $\operatorname{Var}(X_1)$, you can find a lower bound for the required probability using

$$P\left(8\le\frac{S_{20}}{20}\le12\right)=1-\left(\frac{S_{20}}{20}\notin[8,12]\right)\ge1-\frac{\operatorname{Var}(X_1)}{80}.$$

Comment: Sorry Jason, can u show more steps on how you would find the Var(X1)? Also, may I ask how u got 80 as the denominator of Var(X1)?

Comment: How do you normally calculate variance? It's just a simple computation, but you have to do it yourself. You'll see where the $80$ came from in the denominator if you use the facts about variance I provided and work it all out.